# How do I write a PDO prepared statement with multiple values for a field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I write something like this with PDO?:

```
      $query = "SELECT *
      FROM trx
      WHERE item_id = $item_id
      AND NOT (trx_state=3 OR trx_state=4)
```

This is what I have:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
FROM trx
WHERE item_id = :item_id AND NOT (trx_state = :trx_state OR trx_state = :trx_state';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$stmt->execute(array(':item_id' => $item_id, ':trx_state' => '3', '4'));
```

I'm not exactly sure how to set it up where :trx_state has both values 3 and 4.

Comment: How about `trx_state IN (:state_1, :state_2)` and then bind to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:trx_state` doesn't have to match the value you are comparing it against, so you could change the code to:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
FROM trx
WHERE item_id = :item_id AND NOT (trx_state = :trx_state_1 OR trx_state = :trx_state_2';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$stmt->execute(array(':item_id' => $item_id, ':trx_state_1' => '3', ':trx_state_2' =>  '4'));
```

Basically `:trx_state` are just variables and can be named whatever you'd like them to be.